# How can I do sort values in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

After concatenating two dataframe I got this table

```
id = ['A','A','A','A','A','A']
date = ['2022-01-01','2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-01-02','2022-01-03','2022-01-04']
val1=[1,np.nan,2,np.nan,7,8]
val2=[np.nan,3,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan]
pd.DataFrame({'id':id,'date':date,'val_1':val1,'val_2':val2})
```

[image]

As you see, in same day column val_1 is 1 and val_2 is 3, but not in same row.

If it is alternative, I can easily resolve the problem, but there are some exception case like index 7 and 8 (only val 1 is not empty)

Actually, my original table is much bigger. And I want to do same thing when I concatenate more than 2 dataframe.

What I want to get is :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming in the larger context there are more values of ID and that the NaN value can occur in any row then you could use:

```
df = df.groupby(['id', 'date']).max().reset_index()
```

which gives:

```
  id        date  val_1  val_2
0  A  2022-01-01    1.0    3.0
1  A  2022-01-02    2.0    5.0
2  A  2022-01-03    7.0    NaN
3  A  2022-01-04    8.0    NaN
```

Comment: GroupBy.first will compute the first non-null value ;). Otherwise I second your id + date grouping

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Good point. Because we do not know how some larger data set might look, I just took a shot at what the OP might want. But first non-null might also be the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> After concatenating two dataframe I got...

I suspect that you may have some index misalignment issues and that you can get the table in desired format right away by concatenating in a different way.

---

Unfortunately, I can not help you with that without more of your code. If you want to continue from here, then you can use `groupby` + `first`:

```
out = df.groupby("date", as_index=False).first()
```

out:

```
         date id  val_1  val_2
0  2022-01-01  A    1.0    3.0
1  2022-01-02  A    2.0    5.0
2  2022-01-03  A    7.0    NaN
3  2022-01-04  A    8.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid errors (in case you have different ids) you should group by `id` and `date`.

```py
df[['val_1', 'val_2']] = df.groupby(['id', 'date']).ffill().bfill()
r = df.drop_duplicates()

print(r)
```

```
  id        date  val_1  val_2
0  A  2022-01-01    1.0    3.0
2  A  2022-01-02    2.0    5.0
4  A  2022-01-03    7.0    NaN
5  A  2022-01-04    8.0    NaN
```